# Ensuring Radial Progress SVG ReactJs Component Renders consistently on didMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a Radial Progess SVG ReactJs component, you can see working [here](https://codepen.io/sweetog/pen/MWWGzWX):

```
let PROGRESS_RADIAL_ID = 'progressRadial';

function RadialProgress(props) {
    let circumference;
    const [points, setPoints] = React.useState();

    //didMount
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => setPoints(props.points));
     }, []);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const circle = document.getElementById(PROGRESS_RADIAL_ID);
        const radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
        circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
        circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
        circle.style.strokeDashoffset = circumference;
        animateRadial(points / props.threshold * 100);
    }, [points]);

    function animateRadial(percent) {
        const circle = document.getElementById(PROGRESS_RADIAL_ID);
        const offset = circumference - percent / 100 * circumference;
        circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
    }

    return (
        <div className="row progress">
            <div className="col-xs-6 progress-container">
                <svg
                    width="140"
                    height="140">
                    <circle
                        fill="#F7F7F7"
                        r="66"
                        cx="70"
                        cy="70"
                    />
                    <circle
                        stroke="#E3E6E8"
                        strokeWidth="18"
                        fill="transparent"
                        r="44"
                        cx="70"
                        cy="70"
                    />
                    <circle
                        id={PROGRESS_RADIAL_ID}
                        className="progress-radial"
                        strokeWidth="18"
                        fill="transparent"
                        r="44"
                        cx="70"
                        cy="70"
                    />
                    <text
                        x="50%"
                        y="50%"
                        dominantBaseline="middle"
                        textAnchor="middle"
                        className="txt-points">
                        {points}/{props.threshold}
                    </text>
                </svg>
                <input 
                  placeholder={`enter points <= ${props.threshold}`}
                  onChange={(e) => setPoints(e.target.value)} type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<RadialProgress
                  points={30}
                  threshold={50}
                  />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

My problem is that when the component loads the Radial Progress spinner SVG circle will SOMETIMES start full stroke filled and then reduce down, instead of starting at Zero and increasing.

If you enter a points number like 25 in the textbox in the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/sweetog/pen/MWWGzWX) you will see the correct animation.

For the component didMount I have tried using `setTimeout`.

Is there a way that I can get ensure Circle stroke fill starts at 0 and animates around on didMount just like my textbox onChange demonstrates once the component is loaded. Sometimes it works on didMount correctly and other times it doesn't.

Comment: The probleme don't come from your component logic but from you starting css

Comment: @SafiNettah could you help me, elaborate?

Comment: I don't understand the svg but with or without your logic the svg at the first render are filled